# ScrollView scrolls only when the keyboard is visible

Tags: android, scrollviewer

I have  a Frame layout with 6 Linear Layouts , the last one contain 2 buttons i want to scroll beyond this 2 buttons. but it scrolls only when the keyboard is visible and the keyboard popup it pushes the 2 buttons 
**so How can I scroll when the keyBoard is invisible and how can I prevent it from pushing the buttons ?**

here's my code :

```
   <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context="layout.Depart"
android:background="@mipmap/degrade">
<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:fillViewport="true">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">




        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/autoCompleteTextView1"
            android:inputType="textAutoComplete|textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:ems="10"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Destination"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20sp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icondepart"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/display_date"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:hint="Date"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:focusable="false"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/icondate"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"/>


         </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/TimeLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/TimeVol"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Time"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/iconheure"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:focusable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/numv"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Num du vol"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/iconnumvol"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_marginTop="20sp"
        android:background="@drawable/customborder"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:focusable="false">


        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/airp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:gravity="center"
            android:hint="Aéroport"
            android:textColor="#ffffff"
            android:textColorHint="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:drawableLeft="@drawable/iconairport"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="fitXY"
            android:drawablePadding="2dip"
            android:paddingLeft="30sp"
            android:paddingRight="26dip"
            android:focusable="false"/>

    </LinearLayout>




</LinearLayout>




</ScrollView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="63dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="2"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/rechD"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#0A8DB2"
        android:text="Rechercher"
        android:textColor="#ffffff"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/historique"
        android:layout_width="390dp"
        android:layout_height="63dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
        android:background="#FFFF"
        android:text="Historique"
        android:textColor="@color/blue_light"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_gravity="right" />



</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: view scroll only if its getting out of screen. It is scrolling when keyboard is visible,maybe because then your view is bigger than phone screen. Run it on smaller screen and see the effect.

Comment: why don't you use `ScrollView` as `rootLayout` instead `FrameLayout`

Comment: @sharad chauchan i want it to work the same in all devices

Comment: @Devendra because i want to keep buttons separated from the scroll view , if I separte it from the root layout then it will be multiple root tags

Comment: ok you need a part of layout scrollable.and in bottom you need non-scrollable button's layout. you can give height to the child view of scrollview.

Comment: i tryed many values but Im getting the same result , it's not scrolling